# Closed and bounded subset of a metric space which is not complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to find a counterexample for a metric space which is not complete and has a closed and bounded subset. Any hint will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Look at subsets of $\Bbb Q$, the rationals.

Comment: A subset of $Q$ (which is not complete meric space) can be bounded (for example $[0,1]\cap Q$) but I am a bit insecure about the closed part for such a set because I can find a sequence from this set which will converge to some real number not in the set. Am I missing some details?

Comment: @WhatsMyName: You’re thinking of the sets as subsets of $\Bbb R$. Take your space to be $\Bbb Q$, not $\Bbb R$; then $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$, for instance, is a closed set in your space, even though it’s not closed in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @WhatsMyName : Your universe is $\mathbb{Q}$. As far as you are concerned, there is nothing outside it.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @WhatsMyName: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** (For Brian's hint)

Note that $C\subseteq\Bbb Q$ is closed if and only if there is some closed subset $D$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $C=D\cap\Bbb Q$. Similarly for being bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Pick *any* metric space $(X,d)$.
Pick any point $x\in X$. 
Then $\{x\}$ is closed and bounded. (And so is $\emptyset$).